# If a left ideal I of R is an injective R-module then I is a projective R-module. Is the converse true?

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module, injective-module

I was trying to prove the first statement using some characterizations of injective and projective modules but it did not work out. Could someone drop some hints?

Comment: Take R to be any algebra which is not self injective and let I=R. Then I is projective but not injective. Example: $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,xy)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: $\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Z$ is a projective ideal which is not injective (because it is not divisible).